# rails Twitter mentions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

Afternoon everyone,

I'm trying to retrieve some twitter mentions using the rails Twitter gem. Retrieving favourite tweets is pretty straightforward, thanks to Ryan Bates;

```
Twitter.favorites("your_twitter_screen_name", count: 5).each do |tweet| etc...
```

However, when trying to do the same for mentions, which seems to have the same options in the documentation as favorites, it errors out with with;

```
undefined method `each' for "bestluxuryhotel":String
```

(also after removing the each block )

Does anyone know how to correctly enter the mentions options and format?

thanks in advance, Andy

Answer (score 1):

Also the reason that the each block does not work is because you are returned a stringtype instead of an hash or array.

Take a look at the following: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but may be:

```
  -Twitter.favorites("your_twitter_screen_name", count: 5).map do |tweet| etc...
```

Comment: As you can see from the error ouput a string is returned so .map will not be a valid method.